# EMMS doesn't show the track length

Tags: emms

EMMS shows only the playing time, not the track length, e.g.:
02:37         not
02:37/05:49.

The variable `emms-playing-time-display-short-p` has the correct value: nil.
My default player is mplayer, but I've tried also vlc. I never get the track length.

How can I get the format 'playing time/length' ( 02:37/05:49)?

My init.el has for EMMS just these lines of https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Quickstart-Guide:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp/emms/lisp/")  
(require 'emms-setup)  
(emms-all)  
(emms-default-players)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my problem by installing emms from the package repository. Not from the GNU site.