# Getting 'info-playing-time for track in Emms, emms-status

Tags: emms, music-player

I'm trying to use the `emms-state` package to get a nice-looking description of the currently playing track in the mode line. It mostly works -- track name, artist, year, and current timestamp -- but I can't see how long the current track is.

I think the problem is that the `emms-track-get` function doesn't retrieve the `info-playing-time` key/variable. I can test this by editing the `emms-track-description-function` to try to retrieve `info-playing-time`, but the track listings in a playlist buffer do not show this.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm using `emms-player-mpv` as the only player, could that be the origin of this issue?

[This answer to a similar post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32395/24188) suggests  "installing emms from the package repository. Not from the GNU site." Not quite sure what that means, but I'm using `emms` from MELPA.

**EDIT**: Meant `emms-state`, found [here](https://github.com/alezost/emms-state.el), not `emms-status`.

Comment: Where does the `emms-status` package come from?  I cannot find it on MELPA.

Comment: @FranBurstall Whoops, meant `emms-state`: https://github.com/alezost/emms-state.el . But the problem is independent of this package.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue: if I evaluate `(emms-track-get (emms-playlist-current-selected-track) 'info-playing-time)` in the scratch buffer, I get the track length.

Comment: @FranBurstall Hmm... I get `nil` when I do the same (while a track is playing), while e.g. `'info-artist` gives the correct value. Do I need something like `emms-info-libtag`, as in this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45942/24188) (which I've realized is also by you!).

Comment: You probably need some `emms-info-*` loaded (I think the default these days is `emms-info-native` which has no external dependencies and is pretty good).

Comment: Hmm ... `emms-info-function` contained `emms-info-native` and `emms-info-cueinfo`, and adding `emms-info-exiftool` and `emms-info-tinytag` don't make a difference.

Comment: I am mystified then: any of these should populate `info-playing-time`.

Comment: @FranBurstall I've fixed my problem -- I don't think `emms-print-metadata` was available to me before, so I cloned the `emms` repo in order to `make` it. See my answer below. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to add various different `emms-info-functions`, I found [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=emms-help@gnu.org&q=subject:%22How+do+I+get+the+track+info%5C%3F%22&o=newest&f=1) and started working through the suggested solutions.

What I think has ended up working for me is:

- Doing `git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/emms.git` to some local directory (which is what I think [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31371/emms-doesnt-show-the-track-length) was suggesting).
- As suggested in the thread, running `make emms-print-metadata` inside the `emms` directory, and moving `emms-print-metadata` via `sudo cp src/emms-print-metadata /usr/local/bin/`.

I am now able to do `$ emms-print-metadata ~/Music/song.mp3` and get the artist name etc. and now the total time. Restarting `Emacs` to make sure `emms` is configured properly now results in the total time being shown in the mode-line, and `(emms-track-get (emms-playlist-current-selected-track) 'info-playing-time)` working when called via `M-:`.

I had actually found [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22424/emms-is-not-displaying-tag-info-with-libtag?rq=1) describing the same procedure beforehand, although I thought that the problem described there was specific to `emms-info-libtag`.

Also, for anyone else using `emms-mpv-player`, the following might help when adding a new file (e.g. a recently downloaded podcast ep.) to a playlist:

```
(setq emms-player-mpv-update-metadata t)
```

**EDIT**

I realize now that the above is incomplete -- I need

```
(require 'emms-info-libtag)
(setq emms-info-functions '(emms-info-libtag))
```

as well, which I apparently tried at some point. This was after doing another `emms-cache-reset` and having all the time info disappear, (with the currently playing track being showing its time info via `emms-player-mpv-update-metadata`, but unplayed tracks being unaffected).

Comment: Glad this all worked out for you.  I did a little experimentation and it turns out that `emms-info-native` is not extracting the playing time (I am sure it used to).  I shall report this to the emms devs.

Comment: @FranBurstall Ah good - glad it's not something specific to my setup. FWIW I had this issue on Emacs v 27.2 and now on 28.2, with emms version 20220908.122.